# Finding nearest video tags id using jquery of a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a HTML5 video in my current project.I have used video js plugin for this. Now i want to increase(not full screen) the video size when click play button.

**HTML**

```
<video id="big-72_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" data-setup="{ "controls": true,"autoplay": false, "loop": false, "preload": "true" }" preload="true">
<div></div>
<div class="vjs-poster" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="vjs-text-track-display"></div>
<div class="vjs-loading-spinner" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="vjs-big-play-button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0" aria-label="play video">
<div class="vjs-control-bar">
```

I have added on click event in  `<div class="vjs-big-play-button"` to find the id of upper video tag  `<video id="big-72_html5_api"` Please see bellow

**Jquery**

```
    $("#user-table").on('click','.vjs-big-play-button', function() {
    var closest_video_id = $(this).closest( "video" ).find(".vjs-tech").attr( "id" );
    alert(closest_video_id);
});
```

The play button goes to hidden mode when it clicked. See bellow

**When clicked to play button**

```
<div class="vjs-big-play-button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0" aria-label="play video" style="display: none;">
```

I need help to find the video tags id when click to play button.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML-code is not complete is it? The video-tag is missing ending tag `</video>`.

I assume the divs are siblings to the video-tag, so you could use [siblings-selector](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead of closest, which travers up the dom-tree. Also if the class vjs-tech is the class of the video-tag, you might not need the find-part. Depents if you have multiple video-tags, in which case you could do

```
var closest_video_id = $(this).siblings("video.vjs-tech").attr("id");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments.`</video>` is missing here but not in my code. Let try your code for me.